# FileHandling Concept Iterator And not giving expected output

Tags: java

This is java program that will search a string from the particular folder i.e(folder contains no of text files) if the string is there in the folder it is giving perfect output **but if the string is not available in the text file it is not giving any output i need the output as if the string searched in folder is not found then it will show that Nodata Found**

```
public TextSearch() {
    file = new File("C://Users//IBM_ADMIN//Desktop//EVERY WEEK LOGS\\B");
    scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a word");
    word = scanner.nextLine();

    File[] listOfFiles = file.listFiles();
    startSearch(listOfFiles);

    Iterator<String> iterator = counter.keySet().iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        String key = iterator.next();
        System.out.println(key + " contain this word " + word + " " + counter.get(key) + "times");
    }
}

public void startSearch(File[] list) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (list[i].isFile()) {
            try {
                reader = new FileReader(list[i]);
                buffReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
                String line = "";
                while ((line = buffReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    if (line.contains(word)) {
                        if (counter.containsKey(list[i].getName())) {
                            Integer count = counter.get(list[i].getName());
                            count++;
                            counter.put(list[i].getName(), count);
                        } else {
                            counter.put(list[i].getName(), 1);
                        }
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    new TextSearch();
}}
```

Comment: What kind of output?  File, Stdout?, Etc

Comment: If string is not found in search then it will show that No data found just i need condition

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

The trick is to set 0 the filename's counter: `counter.put(list[i].getName(), 0);`

```
public TextSearch() {
    file = new File("C://Users//IBM_ADMIN//Desktop//EVERY WEEK LOGS\\B");
    file2 = new File("C://Users//IBM_ADMIN//Desktop//EVERY WEEK LOGS\\C");

    scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a word");
    word = scanner.nextLine();

    startSearch(file, file2);

    Iterator<String> iterator = counter.keySet().iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        String key = iterator.next();
        if (counter.get(key) == 0) {
            System.out.println(key + " does not contain word " + word);
        } else {
            System.out.println(key + " contain this word " + word + " " + counter.get(key) + "times");
        }
    }
}

public void startSearch(File... list) {
    for (File file : list) {
        File[] listOfFiles = file.listFiles();
        innerStartSearch(listOfFiles);
    }
}    

public void innerStartSearch(File[] list) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (list[i].isFile()) {
            counter.put(list[i].getName(), 0);
            try {
                reader = new FileReader(list[i]);
                buffReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
                String line = "";
                while ((line = buffReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    if (line.contains(word)) {
                        Integer count = counter.get(list[i].getName());
                        count++;
                        counter.put(list[i].getName(), count);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me if i search with this string it is showing output

Comment: Enter a word
Edi inbound
15.txt contain this word Edi inbound 78times
16.txt contain this word Edi inbound 34times
17.txt contain this word Edi inbound 17times

Comment: Enter a word
edi inbound
15.txt does not contain word edi inbound
16.txt does not contain word edi inbound
17.txt does not contain word edi inbound

Comment: I dont understand your question.  You want to search for *edi* and *Edit* and get the same result?

Comment: No if i search with small edi inbound it is not giving the result

Comment: if i search with small Edi inbound it is giving the result

Comment: And one more thing can i give two Folders paths at a time.

Comment: For example in the above program i am giving only one path it is giving expected output if i want to give the path of another folder at a time it is possible?

Comment: Take a look at the answer, I've updated according to your last comment.

Comment: Same output no change